# Objective-C: Returning values by value, reference, and address?

Tags: objective-c, return-value

Does Obj-C return values by value, reference, and address like C/C++ ?
Can you suggest me some documents about this ?

Comment: it returns like C. references to objects are pointers, so those are returned as such.

Answer (score 2):

Everything in Objective-C (not Objective-C++) is passed by value as well as returned by value.

The important thing to remember is that when you have a return value of `NSString *`, for example, the return is still by value. It is the object pointer, not the object, that is being returned. And the pointer is returned by value.

Answer (score 0):

generally by pointer to object if appropriate, but scalar values are fine and legal.

returns by reference wouldn't be legal, except maybe Objective-c++; but I don't know.

in a method the return type is the part after the +/- in the parens...

```
-(int)count;
```

would be a method called count that returns an int

Answer (score 0):

**Objective-C supports  passing parameters by value.**

As Obj-c is super-set of C, so every feature of C is here.

When ever you pass any value to a method you pass its value. In few cases you pass by reference, one quick example is `**error`.

So you change the value of `int` or `NSObject` or any subclasses' object the called method and it **doesn't get reflected in the callee method's value**. You send pointer to the object, not the object itself

Comment: Technically, something like `**error` is still pass by value. You are passing the pointer to the pointer to the object. The pointer to the pointer is passed by value.

Comment: @rmaddy: thanks for clearing that, I was still thinking as all objects are byRef and primitives are byVal.